# How to fix blurry fonts on apple Catalina when using a standard external display

Tags: ios, retina-display

I am on a MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2019) with macOs Catalina 10.15.5

And turns out my external monitor shows blurry fonts. I found a lot of articles explaining the technical reasons for it (the non technical reason is that apple just wants to subdue you into their overpriced stuff)

found this article with a fix, followed every step just to find out that in catalina I cannot touch a read only file system even after disabling  rootless mode

any ideas

https://www.mathewinkson.com/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor